# Safety guarantee for interleaved MPI Isend / Recv

Tags: c++, thread-safety, mpi, communication, openmpi

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079306/safety-guarantee-for-asynchronous-sends-in-mpi) I learned that performing `request = Isend(...); Recv(...); request.Wait();` is *not* guaranteed to work, as `Isend` may not do anything until `request.Wait()`, hence deadlocking at `Recv(...)` (see original question for details).

But what about if `Isend() / Wait()` is performed on another thread than `Recv`? I'm now not directly interested in safety guarantees by the standard. This is because the standard only asserts thread-safety, if the appropriate `Init_thread` method is called and returns the correct level. With my configuration of openMPI this isn't the case. However, I can't see a reason that an implementation actually restricts calls to only from the thread which called `Init_thread` (an actual comparison for the thread id would be necessary). My reasoning is: if I serialize all sends and all recvs, mpi should never be able to notice that I'm using more than one thread.

So my simplified code is this:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <thread>
#include "mpi.h"

void send(int rank, int& item)
{
   MPI::Request request = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Isend(&item, sizeof(int), MPI::BYTE, rank, 0);
   request.Wait();
}

void recv(int rank, int& item)
{
   MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&item, sizeof(int), MPI::BYTE, rank, 0);
}

int main()
{
   MPI::Init();
   int ns[] = {-1, -1};
   int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
   ns[rank] = rank;
   auto t_0 = std::thread(send, 1 - rank, std::ref(ns[rank])); // send rank to partner (i.e. 1 - rank)
   auto t_1 = std::thread(recv, 1 - rank, std::ref(ns[1 - rank])); // receive partner rank from partner
   t_0.join();
   t_1.join();
   assert( ns[0] == 0 );
   assert( ns[1] == 1 );
   MPI::Finalize();
}
```

Explanation of code: Two threads are executed on each processor. One tries to `Isend` some data to the partner and waits until this is done, the other one receives some data from the partner.

Question: Can I safely assume that most implementations of MPI don't choke up on this piece of code?

(Disclaimer: This piece of code is not designed to be exception-safe or particularly beautiful. It's for demo purposes only)

Comment: What you've learned in your related question is wrong.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks for posting an answer there :) This is very good news (well, in part. That means there is a bug somewhere else -.-), because I don't have to throw away my concept _completely_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: Can I safely assume that most implementations of MPI don't choke up on this piece of code?

In practice - yes, if you add synchronisation (which your code is lacking); in theory - no. While it is possible that some implementations allow for serialised calls from different threads at the `MPI_THREAD_SINGLE` level (with Open MPI being such one - see [here](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2010/12/15136.php)), the MPI standard requires that the library must be initialised at the `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED` level. If you intent for your software to be portable and to be able to compile and run correctly with other MPI implementations, you should not rely on some particular Open MPI behaviour.

That said, Open MPI can be configured to support multithreading (`MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`) when the library is built. The default is that MT support is *not enabled* for performance reasons. You can check the state of your particular installation using `ompi_info`:

```
$ ompi_info | grep MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE
     Thread support: poxis (MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE: no, progress: no)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That particular build does not support multithreading and will always return `MPI_THREAD_SINGLE` in the `provided` output argument of `MPI_Init_thread`.

Comment: may I ask which parts of the code need to be synchronized? Does it suffice to wrap `Isend` and `Recv` with the same mutex?

Comment: All MPI calls must be synchronised with a critical section, no matter how it is implemented.

Comment: Thanks, I think I now see a solution to my problem :)

Comment: Note that a single-line solution to your problem exists: `MPI_Allgather(MPI_IN_PLACE, 0, MPI_DATATYPE_NULL, ns, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` (whatever the C++ equivalent is).

Comment: well this is a fairly simplified example code. In my real application, I need to collect results on the master nodes (coming in fairly randomly) and distribute jobs to the nodes. May I ask you to look at the following code and tell me if it's safe? http://pastie.org/8861734

Comment: Honestly, C++ is not my language of choice, but if `std::lock_guard` works as a scoped lock, then it looks pretty safe. Also, if you store the requests in a simple array instead of `std::list`, you could use `MPI_Testany` instead of the loop.

Comment: Indeed, std::lock_guard is a scoped lock. Thanks for your opinion, I feel much safer now :)